# PhoneGap - Is online video streaming possible?

Tags: android, video-streaming, cordova

I have just referred to the [PhoneGap Documentation for Media](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_media_media.md.html), which stated:

> "The Media object provides the ability to record and play back audio files on a device."

I wonder whether video streaming (RTSP) is possible or not with PhoneGap framework? I am trying this out on Android.

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean streaming from your phone? Or to your phone?

Comment: Hi Erik thanks for you reply, I mean streaming to the phone from http, rtsp.. link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, streaming to the device is possible.
Just like with a normal website/webapplication.

I don't know if it's done yet, but this is a audio stream script:
http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/play_an_mp3_audio_stream_in_phonegap

I hope that will get you started.

EDIT:
Maby this will also help you to get started:
http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/584028fe07b0c869/47a1af617c94540a?#47a1af617c94540a

Answer (score 0):

Simply the streaming video can be opened up in a child browser or in App browser to play the video. This solution will work both on Android as well as iOS.

Also if the streaming will be opened in the browser it will appear in full screen mode as q media player will play the video on safari.

Hope this will help.